# Output classpath content from within Spring context configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classpath, applicationcontext

Does *Spring* provide any way to output the actual content of the classpath environment variable when it is loading a resource in a context configuration file?

```
<!-- Import the special context --> 
<import resource="classpath:mySpecialApplicationContext.xml"/>
```

I set the Log4J logging level to ALL for Springframework classes but this value does not appear to be logged by the framework. I am trying to figure out if *Spring* is loading this from a dependency, and I want to see the classpath setting during application runtime. The application is built by *Maven* with many dependencies.

If there are two or more **mySpecialApplicationContext.xml**'s in the classpath, which one does *Spring* use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the relevant (I think) source code at http://goo.gl/9dK2c

In short:

1. No, the classpath is not logged
2. The details of what would be loaded when there is more than one matching resource in the classpath are ClassLoader dependent - the DefaultResourceLoader uses the thread's classloader, but typically, the first one found would be used.

Comment: Thank you for the info, especially the link to the code. If I could see the actual classpath I might be able to ferret out what is being loaded first. So, a question remains: Is there a quick and dirty way to output this from the application context? Logging excepted ...

Comment: I think, but am not certain, that I can stuff the variable into a bean property and when it logs creating the bean (or I can force it manually) then it will log. Nevertheless, I've thought this through and believe that this is the answer given the circumstances and original question. Thanks.